# how to put a y-axis and x-axis label while using html and chartjs

Tags: css, html, chart.js

I have a chartjs plug-ins for drawing chart. I render the chart data to the canvas html control. The problem is while usign chartjs I couldt add x-axis and y-axis label. Any one tel me how to show the labels on left side and bottom of the canvas control.

Comment: I am facing the same problem so i instead use chartNewjs

Answer (score 1):

Axis labels aren't currently supported in chartjs.